# What CI tool would you recommend for GWT development?

Tags: gwt, continuous-integration

I'm about to install a CI tool for a 2 man Java/GWT development "team", and need a brief update on the current state-of-the-art.
I come from a CruiseControl/Ant/rake background (with no Maven experience).

**Requirements:**
* Scripting language (minimal XML config)
* Ant task re-use
* "5 minute" installation and configuration

**Here are some of the contestants:**
Hudson
Bamboo
Rake
Gradle
Buildr
CruiseControl
Cruise

**What CI tool would you recommend in my case ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've set up a Hudson CI for a GWT project with no problem on both Windows and Linux.
I've used ANT tasks to do the different compilations, run JUnit tests and GWT tests, among other things.

You can execute anything you want, ant tasks, command line programs, python scripts,etc.

It also has integration with Bug-Tracking systems like Redmine. And Redmine has integration with Hudson.

And the interface is easy and intuitive, all web based, no xml config files.

Answer (score 3):

For me [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is a best tool for such a thing. Installation is like a breeze. Professional edition is free to use. Ant task reusing is possible. We are reusing all nant tasks from hand written CI 'server'. XML config possible, but UI is great and very easy. Also TeamCity comes with Bug Tracking systems integration.

[Features](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/index.html)

Comment: Can I hook in my own tasks ? What scripting language ?

Comment: it depends on what you want to do. Task is build runner's feature and each build runner has it's own answer (ant, msbuild, rake etc) if you need an additional feature for TeamCity you can write plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use Hudson with Ant task

Answer (score 1):

Buildr has an [open enhancement request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BUILDR-316) with a gwt generation task that works for 1.5.3. It should be simple enough to move it to 2.0 to do what you need.

It's mostly wrapper code around the ant task, using Antwrap, the Buildr java integration, and inserting it into the project lifecycle.